# Crash while aac to mp3 transcoding using libav?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am using libav to decode aac audio and then transcode it into mp3 using libmp3lame.
I know when I decode aac stream I get AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP output and mp3 encoder needs the input in AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P.So I am doing a sample format conversion using swr_convert of libswresample. I know the no. of samples in the decode output is different (i.e. 1024) from the one required by libmp3lame (i.e. 1152) ? for that I am doing buffering as well.

But it is not crashing because of the buffering, it doesn't even come to that part, it crashes in swr_convert.

and if I see the stacktrace using gdb I see the crash happening somewhere in

ff_float_to_int16.next()

What could be the possible problem?